# Function as part of SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I realise the function below is pointless (it is there to explain the question).  Please see the SQL below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[AddOne](@Number int)
returns int
    BEGIN
        return @Number+1
    END

select * from dbusns where reference=dbo.AddOne(1)
```

If I create the function and then execute the SQL statement then it returns the record with reference=2 as I would expect.

Is there a way of executing a function as part of an SQL statement? i.e. without creating it first in SQL Studio manager i.e. without it appearing under: Database/Programmability/Scaler Valued Functions in SQL Studio manager.

Is there another way to approach this without a function perhaps?

Comment: what are you actually trying to do here as you can't call a function that doesn't exist? give us your real problem with some real context

Comment: It would be sort of a lambda function, I don't think is possible in tsql.

Comment: Are you thinking of some facility similar to e.g. [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)s which are a "sort-of" temporary/single use view? If so, no, there's no analogous feature to define other types of objects.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes that is what I was looking for i.e. a CTE for a function.

Comment: I think the bigger question is why don't you want to create the function?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't create/define the function, it does not exist. So you cannot call it.
This is the same in all languages, not just in SQL/T-SQL. Of course, there're
some built-in functions in SQL Server. These you don't need to define yourself.

Comment: Is there another way of approaching this without a function?

Comment: Well, you can do: `select * from dbusns where reference=2`.

Comment: Check your question. Seems you have something in your mind which you think you asked but you did not.

Comment: I explained in the question that it was a trivial example used to explain my question.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you're asking for cannot be done.

[Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (CTEs) provide a means to define a temporary, named result set - like a single-use view, or as the documentation puts things:

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement

There are no analogous features to allow you to declare anything that resembles a user-defined function with the same type of semantics - that it only exist for a single following statement.

So if you do need to encapsulate your logic in something "function-like" (taking parameters and/or returning a scalar instead of a result set), your only choice is a real, permanent function.